# Ranking array items by similarity

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search, multidimensional-array

Say I want to rank users by compatibility, each user has a score in a different attribute (all 1-5):

Smoker: 1
Cleanliness: 3
Night owl: 2

I would like each user array to contain these attributes, I'll have all these users in a multi-dimensional array.

Is there a simple way for me to sort my multi-dimensional array by user compatibility to a given user?

For example, I have `User1: smoker = 1. Cleanliness = 3. Night owl = 2.` whom I would like to sort all other users for compatibility with.

I also have these 2 other users:

`User2: smoker = 5. Cleanliness = 1. Night owl = 4`
`User3: smoker = 1. Cleanliness = 3. Night owl = 2.`

Since `User3` is identical to `User1` (who I wish to rate compatibility with), my array should be sorted as follows: `User1`, `User3`, `User2`. The difficult part seems to be sorting them by closeness, rather than in asc or desc order, say a user had `smoker = 3` I'd either want the next user in the sorted array to have `smoker = 2` or `smoker = 4` (assuming no other use had 3). I'd need a way to gauge closeness overall, throughout each attribute for each user.

Is there a simple way to do this? A general method would be great, a PHP example would be even better.

Comment: Can you show the hard way that you tried and let me try the simple way to do that !

Comment: You can compare and see how close user A is to user B, but you can't order them because you have several features, e.g. 3 features A(0,0,0), B(1,0,0), C(0,1,0), D(2,0,0),E(2,0,0)... distance AB, AC, BD and CE is 1, so you might want to have ABD in sequence and ACE, what you need is a graph then!

Comment: Well this still has the clear order ECABD (or reverse), to bring the point accross you additionally need F(0,0,1) and G(0,0,2) because then you really don't know how to sort the points. (E should have been E(0,2,0) in the last comment)

Comment: You could try to order them, but depending on the data the result could be pretty bad, what you basically are trying to do then is to find the shortest route through all users starting with any user without visiting a user twice... which is pretty complex. (a user is just a point in the multidimensional space, but distance might be a special weighted function)

Comment: Can you post your array structure along with expected output

Answer (score 0):

in such problems you need to weight each part (like `smoker`, `Cleanliness` , `night owl`, `day's chicken`, ...) based on a story, or logic!

for example, I know in my application a `smoker` is more important than a `Cleanliness` as 10 fold, therefore, if I rank a `Cleanliness` like 5, I'd rank `smoker` as 50!

so with `User1: smoker = 1. Cleanliness = 3. Night owl = 2` I'd have

`1*50 + 3*5 + 2*1 = 67`

is such rankings logical?? it depends! as I mentioned earlier...

with a weighted scenario, you can calculate each row's value and sort your collection easily.

Comment: You could do it like that, but consider this: you have two equal important features X and Y, user A has (0,10) and B has (10,0)... couldn't be more different and still gives the same score. Even the route thing would give bad results, shortest route for an arrangement of 2 clouds and 2 points: `[ ]  :  [ ]` the points in the middle are very close but will be very far away from each other in the route.

Comment: ... maybe, again would need more groups and dimensions to demonstrate correctly

Comment: it's not that big deal @maraca, just sort them as you wish, you need a solution for an application not for a theoretical university problem! I know there are many other considerations as well, but it's just an easy solution;)